# Как вычесть средний балл?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне выводит ошибку TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Я хочу вывести средний балл нажатиями на несколько кнопок.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry('450x250')
win.resizable(0,0)
win.title('Средний балл')

def btn_click(item):
    global expression
    expression = list(map(int, item)) / len(item)
    input_text.set(expression)
def bt_clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""
    input_text.set("")
expression = ""

input_text = StringVar()

myLabel1 = Label(win, textvariable=input_text, font=("Montserrat", 15))
myLabel1.pack()

one = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="1", width=4, command=lambda: btn_click(1))
one.pack()
two = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="2", width=4, command=lambda: btn_click(2))
two.pack()
three = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="3", width=4, command=lambda: btn_click(3))
three.pack()
four = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="4", width=4, command=lambda: btn_click(4))
four.pack()
five = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="5", width=4, command=lambda: btn_click(5))
five.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: В `btn_click` аргумент `item` вы передаете число в разных местах. А потом пробуете использовать его как список `len(item)`. Ясно что это не работает.

Comment: expression = list(map(int, item)) / len(item) вы передаете сюда число!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в функцию `btn_click(item)` нужно передать список например `['1','2','3']`

```
expression = sum(map(int, item)) / len(item)
```

`sum(map(int, item))` - `map` преобразует каждый элемент в число, а `sum` подсчитает сумму. Ну, а `len(item)` поделит на количество элементов

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry('450x250')
win.resizable(0, 0)
win.title('Средний балл')


def btn_click(item):
    global expression
    expression = sum(map(int, item)) / len(item)
    input_text.set(expression)


def bt_clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""
    input_text.set("")


expression = ""

input_text = StringVar()

myLabel1 = Label(win, textvariable=input_text, font=("Montserrat", 15))
myLabel1.pack()
mylist = []
one = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="1", width=4,   
             command=lambda: mylist.append(1))
one.pack()
two = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="2", width=4,
             command=lambda: mylist.append(2))
two.pack()
three = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="3", width=4,
               command=lambda: mylist.append(3))
three.pack()
four = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="4", width=4,
              command=lambda: mylist.append(4))
four.pack()
five = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="5", width=4,
              command=lambda: mylist.append(5))
five.pack()
sr = Button(win, font=("Montserrat", 12), bg='#dadada', text="Среднее число", width=20,
            command=lambda: btn_click(mylist))
sr.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Он не подсчитывает средний балл

Comment: исправил ! "Я хочу вывести средний балл нажатиями на несколько кнопок."